# Replace Leading Zeros

Tags: java, regex, formatting

Given a String containing this:

```
Count     %
===========
00000  000%
00012  001%
00905  099%
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Count     %
===========
    0    0%
   12    1%
  905   99%
```

The closest I could get is this:

```
Count     %
===========
    %
 12   1%
 905   99%
```

Using this code:

```
strv.replaceAll("\\b0+", " ")
```

Comment: You should consider assembling your string with the individual numbers already correctly formatted, rather than fixing up the completed string after the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the space to be maintained as-is, it is important that each `0` is matched individually and then replaced with a space: ''. Take a look at this regex:

```
(?<=\b|\G)0(?=\d)
```

- `(?<=\b|\G)` is a positive lookbehind which ensures that the matching `0` is preceeded by either `\b` or `\G`

  - `\b` represents a word boundary which means `\b0` will help match the first zero
  - `\G` helps assert the position at the end of the previous match (which will be after the previous zero). So it will help match the next zero and so on. Thus forming a continuous chain of `0`'s only.
  - Note that since the chain starts with `\b`, there is no way it can be formed for `10000` because the word boundary `\b` is before `1` and not `0`
- Finally a positive lookahead `(?=\d)` also needs to be added because if an input contains only zero's then we need to leave one zero behind. This positive lookahead tells the engine to **match all zeros which are followed by a number**. So, if input is `0000`, then regex will match first 3 `0`'s because *last one isn't followed by a digit*.

Usage

```
strv.replaceAll("(?<=\\b|\\G)0(?=\\d)", " ")
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Np7Df7/4/)

**EDIT:** Updating as per @SebastianProske's suggestions. Thanks!